# how to make nav toggle button show in new line

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, nav

hi i'm new to bootstrap
i wonder how to make nav toggle button in new line
i always get something like this

[image]

it's really close to some text (nav-brand)
and i think it's ugly look

this is my code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">            
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing: `<div class="navbar-header"></div>`

**Full Code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><!-- Add this div here -->
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div><!-- Make sure to end this div here -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```